# Doctrine - Custom form field based on query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 2 linked entities: User and Acess. I want my doctrine User entity to have a field that informs me if the user has acesses or not. 
I can't do a simple OneToMany relationship between the two tables, because there is thousands of acesses and it would be too costly to get thousands of records from the database once I only need to know if there is any.
What I would want is a field linked to a native query like:

```
select * from accesses where user = <whatever> limit 1
```

More specifically, something like:

```
/**
 * USer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=300, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Query="select exists (select id_acesses from accesses where user = "$id" limit 1)"
     */
    private $hasAcesses;
}
```

Is this possible ? is there another way to do this ?

**Edit:**

based on @Otanaught answer below, I have done some tests:

Using a OneToMany relation with EXTRA_LAZY fetch:

user-getAccesses()->isEmpty() selected the whole collection

user-getAccesses()->count() used count(*) in the database which took 243ms to return

for comparasion my query above who did what I want took 12ms in average with peeks of 2ms or even 1ms.

Maybe the good folks at doctrine could implement this at isEmpty for extra lazy queries ?

Thanx @Otanaught

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine does not provide an annotation that allows you to specify a query for a property of an entity ([Annotation reference](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html)). You could create a [custom method in your repository](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories) to implement the check. Did you measure how costly the relation would be? With correct relations and indexes this should be a none issue, because doctrine lazy loads the relation? [Check the doctrine documentation about extra lazy collections](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/improving-performance.html#extra-lazy-collections).

Comment: well actually, reading this docs, extralazy association has what I need. It would be better still if I can access Collection's isEmpty method without triggering the load. Do you know if it's available ?

Comment: Actually calling count on extra lazy collections does not load the full collection. The documentation about extra lazy collections states this.

Comment: I have read. But it's that when working with large result sets, even a count can be constly. So that's why I thought in using isEmpty instead. But I'm testing. BRB in a couple of minutes with the results.

Comment: How do you want to check if something is there without asking? :) Even without an ORM this wouldnt be possible.

Comment: Well beacause it depends on the count() implementation. Se the query I gave as an example above ? For my needs it would be much less costly than any count estimate.

Comment: Using [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) the query should as follows, please note i did not test it:

    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT partial {u.id} FROM User u JOIN u.id = ?1)');
    $query->setParameter(1, 123455);
    $exists = $query->getResult();

Comment: Yes but, I can't use DQL in an entity, can I ?

Comment: There is no known way to me. Thats why repository classes exists.

Comment: Ok.. for now count() will suffice. 243ms is low enough. Again thanks for your help.